# Drag and Drop with a custom User Control

Tags: c#, events, drag-and-drop

I have to make a program which has 3 forms and each form contains 2 custom user controls.

I have to make the user controls switch places (one with another).

I'm using the drag & drop event, so by mouseDown event I catch the first user control,
though, I don't know how to catch the second control, which the mouse is 
being dropped on.

basically, Iv'e created (in the class) a temp variable which is a custom eventArgs (derives from
EventArgs), 
The custom EventArgs class contains 2 variables (usercontrol1 and usercontrol2)
and in the mouseDown event Iv'e initialized the usercontrol1 with the sender object.

So basically, the question is- how do I intiazlize the usercontrol2 variable with the
usercontrol which the mouse is being dropped on.

NOTE:  I HAVE 6 Controls - 3 forms- so it's dynamic!! Which means, that I may want to exchange the control's places between the forms- I have to save the 2 controls I WANT to exchange between!.

Thanks!

Comment: nope, I have 3 forms (6 controls) and I want to change between the controls from different forms (not always though), so I do have to save the control.

Comment: so you want to move controls of a form across the forms?

Comment: @user1362804 So your question is how to capture the user control in mouse down event and drop in other form?

Comment: my question is how to capture the user control which I dropped the mouse on.  For example, I've started from control 1 in form 1, and dropped the mouse (stopped handling it) on  control 0 in form 2, so how do I capture (place in a variable) the control 0 in form 2(?) thx

Comment: Just pass the user control instance to the DoDragDrop() method.  You'll get it back in the DragEnter and DragDrop event handlers.  You now have the two references you need, *this* and the e.Data.GetData() return value.